# What is BIg Commerce Development process?

Tags: bigcommerce

I am finding it difficult locating resources for custom programming, e.g. themes, including and changing JS, altering or adding PHP files, etc. 
For instance, does uploading files overwrite installed template files? Like child-themes?

Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like you are coming from a WordPress background; BigCommerce is vastly different in regards to its template engine, but furthermore it is a closed source platform, meaning that you cannot upload or execute server side programs to it. The best way to become familiar would be to access the 'Edit HTML' section, via 'My Themes'. Asking a specific question would yield better responses here as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For custom programming you are meant to use their API - could I just check you have reviewed the developer documentation here: https://developer.bigcommerce.com/

You are not able to upload server side code like PHP to the big commerce server so it you want to pull Big Commerce data you will need to run the PHP on an external server and then use the Big Commerce API.

Regarding templates, you can create custom templates files by uploading prefixing the template file with an underscore "_" e.g. _CustomCategory.html. By using this approach you will not overwrite the existing template files and your modifications will be easier to maintain in the future.